# How to convert a “mm/yyyy” varchar to datetime?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a date which stored in `"mm/yyyy"` format and its datatype is varchar.

I want to get date in `"mm/dd/yyyy"` format

eg : `4/2013` stored in the database

I want

```
30/4/2013
```

Comment: Where the `dd` Part gone..?

Comment: So you want the last day of the month? Do you want the output as a date or as an ambiguously formatted regional string? You can't have both.

Comment: I want Last Date Of Month as Date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DECLARE @d VARCHAR(32) = '4/2013';

-- as a datetime

SELECT DATEADD(DAY,-1,DATEADD(MONTH,1,
  CONVERT(DATETIME,'1/'+@d,103)));

-- as a date

SELECT CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(DAY,-1,DATEADD(MONTH,1,
  CONVERT(DATETIME,'1/'+@d,103))));

-- as an ambiguously formatted regional string

SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(10), DATEADD(DAY,-1,DATEADD(MONTH,1,
  CONVERT(DATETIME,'1/'+@d,103))),103);
```

Is that annoying? Good! Store a date the right way in the first place. And stop thinking about the database as a place to store / present dates in a specific format - do the formatting at the client where necessary, and usually a regional format is a bad idea anyway unless you have a very limited audience.

Comment: CONVERT(CHAR(10), DATEADD(DAY,-1,DATEADD(MONTH,1, CONVERT(DATETIME,'1/'+@d,103))),103) it is work , In above little change, I correct it please review it  Thanks

Comment: Sorry, typed that on my iPad, not sure where the `1`s went.